# Convert Enumeratee to Future[List] Scala

Tags: scala, playframework, loops

What is a standard way to convert `Enumerator` to `Future[List]` in Play Scala framework?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use method `run` with parameter of type `Iteratee[E, List[E]]` to get `Future[List[E]]`.

There is method `getChunks`, that creates `Iteratee[E, List[E]]`:

```
myEnumerator run Iteratee.getChunks
```

You could use `Iteratee.fold` to create such `Iteratee` manually. In case you want to preserve elements order you could use `reverse` on `List`.

```
myEnumerator run Iteratee.fold(List.empty[E]){ (l, e) => e :: l } map { _.reverse }
```

Comment: Or you could use `Iteratee.getChunks`, which does precisely this for you.